# Jmeter Issues with JDBC Request and variables

Tags: postgresql, variables, jdbc, jmeter

I'm having a few issues with Jmeter and storing/using variables from them:

1. I have a JDBC request which does a VERY simple "select statement" with the following sql:

   ```
   select count(member_id) from member
   ```

This is then stored in a variable named count. I know what the count should be (should be 312), but the value count_1 gets is 40077. What is even more troubling is at some point, it started working and getting the correct count. Any idea what is going on?

1. In a seperate JDBC request, I retrieve a list of members:

   ```
   select member_id from members
   ```

This is stored in a variable named members.  Then I created a THIRD JDBC request to query and grab a random member:

```
select * from members where member_id = ?
```

In "Parameter values", I put in `${__V(member_${__Random(1,10)})}` (note I put 10, not $count because I can't even get it to work correctly with a hard coded number).  I see that this gets parsed correctly, but the error I get is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "member_7"
```

So it's not substituting the member_7 variable's value.  Instead it's just passing the string.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the JDBC Request that runs the "Select member_id from members" is storing that value in member variable.  Jmeter will create a member_# variable which holds the count of the results, and then member_1, member_2 (for as many members that were returned from the query).  I don't want to pick the same one everytime, so I want to randomly select one of the results by adding a random number after the member_

Comment: So following a suggestion from someone, I tried using the random variable control.  It allows you to have a random number generated and pre-pend text before it.  This works perfect for my case of wanting "member_" + random number.  The only problem I have is that the min and max values seem to only accept numbers.  I tried putting my ${count_1} variable here to make sure I limit the count to how many members exist in the db but it does not seem to work. Is there a way to specify a variable in the min/max fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you have table member, where you have some member_id in this way (for example):

```
| member_id |
+-----------+
| 1         |
| 2         |
| 1         |
```

And you would like to count UNIQUE members from this table, you must use SELECT in this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) FROM member;
```

When you miss keyword DISTINCT, you will get only a COUNT of lines in the table.

The second SELECT you have to use in similar way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT member_id FROM member;
```

And the last question is, why you tried to integer value assign a value like 'member_7'?